# Invalid object name - derived table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I was testing derived table queries. When I run below query, it shows the error.

```
`Invalid object name 'result'.`
```

I am really surprised. Could any one please clear my doubt why it is throwing this strange error.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM (SELECT
  1 AS ID,
  'Mike' AS Name) [result]
WHERE result.ID NOT IN (SELECT
  ID
FROM [result]
WHERE Name = 'Mike')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't reuse a derived table using that syntax.
Use [CTE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx) (Common Table Expression) for that.

```
with [result] as 
  (SELECT
  1 AS ID,
  'Mike' AS Name) 

SELECT
  *
FROM result
WHERE result.ID NOT IN (SELECT
  ID
FROM [result]
WHERE Name = 'Mike')
```

Comment: It could be better if you explain why I can't reuse a derived table using that syntax?

Comment: It is simply not supported by the language which offers another alternative.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. :)